# What is a good alternative to iTunes on Linux?

Tags: software-rec, music, streaming, music-player

I use iTunes primarily to sync music to my iPod, but other than that I use it to play music as opposed to streaming like Pandora or Spotify. I'm trying to completely convert from Win7 to Fedora and if I was able to have my music in a Linux environment, I'd be one step closer.

Comment: What are you using iTunes for? When asking for software recommendations like this, always say what you use the program for, otherwise you may get suggestions of programs that lack the one feature you care most about. Also, people might not know the other program you've been using: assume we haven't heard of iTunes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

[iTunes alternatives - linux](http://alternativeto.net/software/itunes/?platform=linux)
[iTunes open source alternatives](http://www.lidux.de/linux-tutorials/115-itunes-open-source-alternativen.html)

Answer (score 3):

For simply playing music, I've never been able to go past [Amarok](http://amarok.kde.org/). It's also possible to [sync your iPod](http://amarok.kde.org/wiki/Media_Device%3aIPod) using it.

Answer (score 3):

For copying stuff into your iPod, use `gtkpod`, works for my iPod Shuffle at least

For streaming, and support of spotify / last.fm etc., use `clementine`.

Answer (score 3):

I like [Clementine](http://www.clementine-player.org/), it's a good clone of what [Amarok 1.x](http://amarok.kde.org/) used to be like before they (IMO) messed it up with the version 2.x release.

On a more general note, pretty nearly anything is better than iTunes - Apple is usually excellent with user-interface design, but that program is an unusable abomination. I'd think "WTF were they thinking?" except that it's obvious that usefulness to the user was decidedly a second-class consideration compared to being a walled-garden storefront for Apple to sell music.

Comment: oh yeah, just remembered - Clementine is cross-platform, versions are available for Linux, Mac, and Windows. Same is true for Amarok (and several other Linux music players/organisers).